# Unity's Mesh.CombineMeshes() seems to delete vertex information

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `MeshFilter` where I want to attach new meshes to the existing mesh, meaning I want to add additional vertecies, triangles, normals to the existing mesh.

Here is how I would do it now:

```
    MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh newMesh = new Mesh();
    newMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
    // information set here is calculated beforehand
    newMesh.SetVertices(MeshVertecies);
    newMesh.SetNormals(MeshNormals);
    // GenerateTriangles creates the correct triangle indices 
    newMesh.SetTriangles(GenerateTriangles(DepthSource.DepthWidth, DepthSource.DepthHeight), 0);



    if (firstMeshFlag)
    {
        meshFilter.sharedMesh = newMesh;
        firstMeshFlag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Mesh oldMesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
        Mesh combinedMesh = new Mesh();

        try
        {
            combinedMesh.CombineMeshes(new CombineInstance[]
            {
                new CombineInstance
                {
                    mesh = newMesh
                },
                new CombineInstance
                {
                    mesh = oldMesh
                }
            });

            meshFilter.sharedMesh = combinedMesh;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //This just prints debug information to the UI 
            //(Application running on Android using Google Depth API, which is why I can't debug
            DebugInformation.Instance.AppendDebugText("\ncombine err: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The first time this is called, the resulting mesh is rendered as expected, however the second time around (`firstMeshFlag = false`), the mesh disappears.

*The application is running on an android phone and uses Google AR as well as Googles Depth API, which as far as I know, doesn't yet support instant preview. So my only means of debugging right now, is to print information to the UI.*

**What I found out so far:**
The reason the mesh disappears is, that while it holds the correct amount of vertecies, all the vertecies and normals values are set to zero.

1. Is `CombineMeshes()` really the only means of adding additional vertecies, normals, etc. to an exisiting mesh?
2. What could be the reason for the described issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer was quite simple. I didn't add a transform matrix to the `CombineInstance`s and the argument `useMatrices` in the `CombineMeshes()` method defaults to true.

Therefore the solution was as easy as changing use of the method to the following:

```
combinedMesh.CombineMeshes(new CombineInstance[]
            {
                new CombineInstance
                {
                    mesh = newMesh
                },
                new CombineInstance
                {
                    mesh = oldMesh
                }
            }, true, false);
```